# How to send an array of JSON string to API in c#

Tags: c#, json, string, dotnet-httpclient

I am looking to send this array of JSON strings to my API. I am having few issues.....

- should my class model be an array as well ?
- When I deserialize, I get an error message: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Model' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Body to send is:

```
 [
{
    "ObjectId" : "1270583B-208A-427F-8B1E-B20E6271D0FE",
    "ObjectTypeId" : 1
},
{
    "ObjectId" : "1270583B-208A-427F-8B1E-B20E6271D0FE",
    "ObjectTypeId" : 2
},
{
    "ObjectId" : "1270583B-208A-427F-8B1E-B20E6271D0FE",
    "ObjectTypeId" : 3
}
]
```

My model class is :

```
class Model
{

        public string ObjectId { get; set; }
        public int ObjectTypeId { get; set; }


}
```

I am deserializing my Httpcontent   like that:

```
static object Content;
string HttpContent= "[{\"ObjectId\" : \"1270583B-208A-427F-8B1E- B20E6271D0FE\" , \"ObjectTypeId\" : 1 }]";
Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(Httpcontent);
```

Comment: deserializing into Model[] should work.

Comment: That worked :) Thank you

Comment: deserializing into List<Model> would also work (the one answer you got...can mark that as answer I suppose)

Answer (score 1):

You should try to deserialize as a List of Model objects.

```
Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(Httpcontent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add [] to my model. Thank you @Johannes.colmsee

```
Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model[]>(Httpcontent);
```